# How to correctly remap values from prisma to typescript types?

Tags: node.js, database, express, backend, prisma

I am currently building an ecommerce webshop with my backend using express and the Prisma ORM.

The system itself is running, but there probably can be optimized a lot, especially regarding my types and how I used Prisma because that was the first time i used an ORM.

Code like this is scattered all over my project. For bigger more complex tables with relations some files have around 900 lines which isn't the best. It's also not very readable at all.
Currently I am remapping my Prisma values to my Format i need it in the frontend like this:

```js
 try {
    const paymentMethods = await prisma.paymentMethod.findMany({
      include: { name: true, paymentFee: true },
    });

    const formattedPaymentMethodsArray: PaymentMethod[] = [];

    paymentMethods.forEach((pm) => {
      const formattedName: Localized[] = [];
      const formattedPaymentFee: PriceObject[] = [];

      pm.name.forEach((name) => {
        const nameObject: Localized = {
          id: name.id,
          text: name.name,
          langCodeId: name.langcodeId,
        };
        formattedName.push(nameObject);
      });

      pm.paymentFee.forEach((fee) => {
        const feeObject: PriceObject = {
          id: fee.id.toString(),
          price: Number(fee.price),
          priceClassId: fee.priceClassId.toString(),
        };
        formattedPaymentFee.push(feeObject);
      });

      const formattedPaymentMethod: PaymentMethod = {
        id: pm.id,
        key: pm.key,
        name: formattedName,
        paymentFee: formattedPaymentFee,
      };

      formattedPaymentMethodsArray.push(formattedPaymentMethod);
    });
```

This is the part of the schema.prisma file of the PaymentMethod

```
model PaymentMethod {
  id         Int                 @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  key        String
  name       PaymentMethodName[]
  paymentFee PaymentFee[]
  orders     Order[]

  @@map("payment_method")
}
```

This is the PaymentMethod interface

```js
export interface PaymentMethod {
  id: number;
  key: string;
  name: Localized[];
  paymentFee: PriceObject[];
}
```

This is the Localized Interface

```js
export interface Localized {
  id: number;
  langCodeId: number;
  text: string;
}
```

This is the PriceObject Interface

```js
export interface PriceObject {
  id: string;
  price: number;
  priceClassId: string;
}
```

What are the best practices to use here instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the repetitive formatting logic into utility functions to avoid redundancy. This will help you keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and make it more maintainable.

Example:

```
const formatName = (names: any[]): Localized[] => names.map(name => ({
  id: name.id,
  text: name.name,
  langCodeId: name.langcodeId,
}));

const formatPaymentFee = (fees: any[]): PriceObject[] => fees.map(fee => ({
  id: fee.id.toString(),
  price: Number(fee.price),
  priceClassId: fee.priceClassId.toString(),
}));

// Usage
const formattedPaymentMethodsArray = paymentMethods.map(pm => ({
  id: pm.id,
  key: pm.key,
  name: formatName(pm.name),
  paymentFee: formatPaymentFee(pm.paymentFee),
}));
```

Comment: Thanks thats already a good way to make it more readable.

But Is that even the correct way to go? Should you remap your values like that when using prisma? Or should you just send the object to the frontend as is? How do you get type safety in the frontend with the prisma types then?